# Comparar el contenido de strings python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estaba haciendo un programa y me tope con un problema. ¿Cómo puedo comparar el inicio de 2 strings?

Por ejemplo, tengo un string:

`string1 = "hola soy juan"`

Y otro que dice:

`string2="juan"`

¿Cómo puedo saber si el segundo string empieza con "juan"? (el segundo string siempre va cambiando lo que tiene guardado)

Answer (score 1):

existe la función startswith que lo que basicamente hace es mirar si una cadena comienza con una subcadena definida, ej:

```
if cadena1.startswith("juan"):
    print("hola Juan")
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sería definiendo búsquedas acotando los caracteres a buscar, claro está que debemos conocer previamente la longitud de caracteres a buscar. En este caso sabemos que "juan" tiene 4 caracteres, con lo cual lo indicamos con [0:5]. Una vez conocido este dato, ya podemos crear bucles o comparaciones a nuestra elección para optimizar el código.

```
cadena1 = "juan"
cadena2 = "hola soy juan"
if cadena1[0:5] == "juan":
  print ('La cadena1 empieza por "juan"')
else:
  print ('La cadena1 no empieza por "juan"')

if cadena2[0:5] == "juan":
  print ('La cadena2 empieza por "juan"')
else:
  print ('La cadena2 no empieza por "juan"')
```